# Same program, same code, one requires a object reference, the other doesn't. What could cause this?

Tags: c#, object-reference

I wrote exactly this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class formTabelasPsi : Form
  {
     char sepdec = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
```

and

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    //some code
    char sepdec = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
```

It's might seem unbelivable, but on the first app `formTabelasPsi` , the char `sepdec` isn't recognized unless I declare it `static`

This is also happening to a `private void` method I copied from `Form1`. They wont work unless I declare them `static` on the first app.

What kind of sorcery is this?

Edit: I don't wanna share them, so this is not a duplicate.

The `//somecode` is totally unrelated to `sepdec` and it's not inside a method.

It's working on`formTabelasPsi` only when I set them to `static`, but I will post where I'm using them.

Note this is the code on `formTabelasPsi`, the one that requires `static`

```
public static void actualizartabelaspsi(string path)
    {

        DataTable psisEC111 = DataAccess.Instance.TabelasPsis.Tables[1];

        DataAccess.Instance.tabelapsisEN111.Rows.Clear();


        psisEC111.ReadXml(path);

        string tipodesepdec = psisEC111.Rows[0]["valor"].ToString();

        if (tipodesepdec != sepdec.ToString())
        { 
                 converteficheirogravadoparaodotcomma2(path);
         }
 }
```

later on...

```
private static void converteficheirogravadoparaodotcomma2(String path)
{
}
```

Comment: Define, "not recognised".. how are you trying to access it, with an instance or the class name?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with it isn't recognized? Do you get an compilation error or isnt it printed at runtime or something like that?

Comment: What's the code behind `some code` ?

Comment: Note that they're both partial classes.  What's in the rest of the declaration/code of `Form1` and `formTabelasPsi`?

Comment: In the first case you defined `sepdec` outside a class method; in the second case you defined `sepdec` inside a class method.

Comment: You need to  do some research into what the word `static` means, I would give you a link to point you in the right direction but I think you would benefit more by doing your own research (my link would probably be from msdn if that helps your research).

Comment: @Sayse Doesn't `static` mean that a `string` stays a `string` and a `float` stays `float`  across different classes?

Comment: @ng80092b - No, essentially it changes a variables scope

Comment: @Sayse to msdn i shall go :)